# React native image scaling

Tags: react-native

I have a background image however on different screen sizes it scales differently. If you look at the bottom of the on the footprints it is easy to identify how different they are. I basically want these two images to be identical on all screen resolutions. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, ImageBackground, TouchableHighlight, Image, Dimensions} from "react-native";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

class SignInUpGender extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground style={styles.Image} source={require('../../assets/images/background_loading2.jpeg')}>

            </ImageBackground>

        )
    }
}
export default connect()(SignInUpGender);


const entireScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
EStyleSheet.build({$rem: entireScreenWidth / 380});

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
    Image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemode

This might be the prop you need to use. It is applicable for ImageBackground too.